How to set up the control block sample time to filter the signal (i.e., remove the switching frequency)?
There is a similar question asked many years ago, and the answer (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/83871/56197) suggests setting the switching frequency to be equal to the control loop frequency.
I have tried to implement this in MATLAB Simulink to test.

I am using a triggered subsystem on the rising edge and feeding in the inverter-measured signals (AC voltage and current). The switching frequency is \$f_\text{sw}\$, and the block sample time is \$1/f_\text{sw}\$. Sample time and PWM triangle are synced:

But when I look at the signals, I have noticed there is an offset. As it can be seen in the figure below. Blue is the original measured signal, and the red is the sampled signal at \$f_\text{sw}\$.

Details:


Later, when I am converting the signals to \$dq0\$ for the closed-loop control, the \$0\$ axis has an offset. So the sampling introduces an offset.

Is anyone experiencing this?
How to properly set the control sample time to get the 'symmetrical' signals?
Note that the sample time is synchronised with the PWM triangle -1. In the digital system I will be using the ePWM MATLAB Simulink block, and all will be synchronised to Counter equals to zero... where the counter starts from zero, and in the numerical model it starts from -1 (see first Fig.).

Measured where in which circuit?

@Lundin I have created a three-phase inverter with an LC output filter MATLAB Simulink model, which I am using. I am measuring output line-to-line, line-to-neutral, and load current and then sampling for the control.

My point is: why do you think the problem is related to the theoretical model rather than your physical circuit, or the measurement itself?

@Lundin I just read in the reference that if you set the control sample time to be equal to the switching frequency, you don't need to filter measured signals.... However, in my case, I get the offset on the signal, which affects my control circuit.... Are there any examples I can use/look at to either verify the method or my model?
